# Explanation of Using Pointers to Pointers (**) for Dynamic 2D Array Declaration in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-arrays

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm currently working on a C++ project involving dynamic 2D arrays, and I'm having difficulty understanding the use of pointers to pointers (**) when declaring such arrays. Additionally, the need for a loop during the declaration process is unclear to me.

Here's a snippet of the code I'm working with:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int **matrixPtr; // 2D array declaration
    cout << "Enter the number of rows: ";
    int row; // Defining row
    cin >> row; // Initializing the value of row from the user
    cout << "Enter the number of columns: ";
    int col; // Defining column
    cin >> col; // Initializing the value of column from users
    matrixPtr = new int *[row]; // Allocating 2D array dynamically

    // Loop for dynamic allocation of each row
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
       matrixPtr[i] = new int[col];
    }
    // Rest of the code...
```

Could someone please explain why pointers to pointers (**) are used in this context and why a loop is necessary during the dynamic allocation process? Any insights, clarifications, or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's not the greatest code example one could use. Fix your syntax. Please ues star signs only for pointer usage. Don't use them to format your code (it does not even work anyways).

Comment: Do you know what `matrixPtr = new int *[row]` means?

Comment: You can think of it as a 2D array of data, but instead of storing the data in a data structure, you store an address where that data is stored.  Pointers to data significantly improve performance for repetitive operations such as traversing strings, lookup tables, control tables and tree structures. It is often much cheaper in time and space to copy and de-reference pointers than it is to copy and access the data to which the pointers point.

Comment: `int **matrixPtr;` This is not a 2D array. A 2D array would be, for instance `int matrix[12][4]`. What you have there is a pointer to a pointer to an int. Nothing more. **Do not use that to make "2D arrays", as this is not what it does**.

Comment: Why not use `std::vector`?

Comment: "_Why do we use pointers to pointers while declaring dynamic 2d array in c++?_" We _don't_, or certainly **shouldn't**, when an `std::vector< std:vector<int> >` is the proper way to do it in C++, instead of using an ancient anti-pattern grandfathered-in from C.

Comment: It's not required to use a double pointer to make a dynamic 2D array. It's one way but certainly not the only way. If you have a method that works in a different way then go for it.

Comment: There are no dynamic 2D arrays in C++, which is why if you want something like that you have to build your own, using a double pointer or using some other method. Your approach maybe better or worse than a different approach but if the code you write behaves like a dynamic 2D array, then it is a dynamic 2D array.

Comment: @underscore_d vector<vector<int>> creates an array of arrays... just as it says. This is not the same thing as a 2d array. For starters, a real 2D array of 1000*1000 items would allocate 1 block of 1000000 items, while a vector<vector<int>> will perform 1001 allocations of 1000 items each.

Comment: @spectras Fair point. Still, OP is not actually allocating a 'real' 2D array either, but instead an array of 1D arrays, which _is_ what `vector<vector>` does.

Comment: @underscore_d> true, which is why I wanted to address the initial confusion. Then I totally agree with you, if what he wants really is a vector of vectors rather than a 2d array, your suggestion is definitely the best.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Roughly a 2D matrix is just a 1D matrix whose elements are 1D matrix of elementary elements, thus an array of array. Right?

Then if you want to allocate it dynamic you have:

1. the type for the elements, say `int`,
2. the type for storing a dynamic array of elements, then `int *`, pointer to int; how many, say `cols`,
3. the type for storing a dynamic array of 1D-arrays, then `int **`, pointer to pointer to int, how many, say `rows`.

Then you need a loop at (3) because you need to allocate independently each 1D-array of size `cols`... You have `rows` rows each one of size `cols`.

Comment: Can the downvoter explain? Do they not like the "Roughly" because a 'real' 2D array would only perform a single allocation, instead of being an array of arrays?

Comment: Very confusing, and wrong: `int *` does not store an array of elements, but a pointer to an int (which may or may not be part of an array). This is deceptive in this answer, because it makes the reader think that `int **` then stores an array of arrays, or a pointer to such thing. That's simply not the case. Which you can easily check: range-for will not work, `std::begin`, `sizeof` or `std::size` neither.

Comment: [continued]. With that mental model, it makes it impossible to explain the difference between `int ** a`, `int (*a)[42]`, `int * a[42]`, `int a[42][42]` or `int (*a)[42][42]`. While all of those are very different.

Comment: @spectras what is confusing is the truth at first place. So you need something much simpler. You can't expect everybody understand everything about pointers, arrays, etc at the first explanation. Ok, it may not be the goal of SO. Isn't it the point of all comments on the question?